# How to add (un)resolved status field to Drupal 6 forum?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, forum

I would like to extend my Drupal 6 forum to easily see which questions have been resolved and which are still unresolved. I thought the best way would be to add a *status* field, but I can not find a way to add this.

What is the best way to easily mark forum topics in Drupal as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module. It will allow you to designate arbitrary "flags" to be associated with  a post. It's super flexible.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks, Hendrik.